# What is the major product of the reaction between 4-chlorobut-1-ene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

> [image: What is the major product of the reaction between 4-chlorobut-1-ene?]

When acetic acid looses hydrogen, an acetate ion is formed which attacks 4-chlorobut-1-ene, forming methyl butenoate. How does the cyclic structure form?
Does the lone pair of oxygen attack the butene moiety internally?

Answer (score 3):

> In solvolysis of simple primary cyclopropylmethyl systems the rate is
>   enhanced because of participation by the $\sigma $ bonds of the ring. The ion
>   that forms initially is an unrearranged cyclopropylmethyl cation that is
>   symmetrically stabilized, that is, both the 2,3 and 2,4 $\sigma $ bonds help
>   stabilize the positive charge(**page 464 ,*JerryMarch ,Advanced Organic Chemistry
>   Reactions, Mechanisms,and Structure,Sixth Edition***).

The reaction of various cyclopropylmethyl systems are given below.

[image]

In the question 4-chlorobut-1-ene  (**1**) undergoes rearrangement as shown in the **scheme 3 and scheme 4** to give **1a, 1b and 1**c.Assuming solvolysis with acetic acid ,**1a, 1b and 1**c would give **2, 3 and 4**.

[image]

Comment: Which would be the major product? I feel it would be 3

Comment: @thewitness , the product composition could follow the one I suggested in Scheme 1.But this reaction is with acetic acid and composition may change.Access to a journal could verify or disprove it.